# reconfigure parameters for uvc_camera or uvc_cam2

Tags: ros, uvc-cam, webcam, parameter, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I would like to use the uvc_camera driver but the image has some weird coloring. It seems that the parameters are not right. Therefore, I found would like to adjust them.
I found a [post](http://answers.ros.org/question/10236/logitech-webcams-very-dark-when-using-uvc_cam/) here were someone says that he uses the dynamic_reconfigure tool. But when i tried to use it were just the jpg quality an adjustable parameter and nothing more.

So I used ucvdynctrl (which is kind of awkward to use) and I after an hour of trail and error I still don't have a good setting. I would be glad if someone could?would share their parameter for a Logitech c920.

Additionally: I saw the option of different pixelformats when I launch the package. But how can I select them. There is no pixelformat parameter.

Would be great to get your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51094/reconfigure-parameters-for-uvc_camera-or-uvc_cam2/) by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 447 on 2012-12-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on 2012-12-27**:
thank you! that is excellently what I was looking for. Do you know how I set the mjpeg compression for the uvc_driver? Its easily done in guvcview but I coundn't find a solution for the uvc_camera package...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You may try `guvcview` - GUI for UVC cameras. It is possible that something wrong with White Balance options. Mine WB Temperature is set automatically to 5300, just to give you the reference.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2012-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1